# "Service xxx has a dependency on a non-existent service" which seems not true?

Tags: symfony

I got some application i'm migrating to Symfony 4.1. After enabling `container.autowiring.strict_mode: true` I got an error reguarding our custom `Router`

```
The service ".service_locator.G69Xsbl.Foo\Bundle\Admin\SiteRoutingBundle\Routing\AdminSiteRouter" 
has a dependency on a non-existent service "Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\LoaderInterface".
```

The class looks like:

```
<?php

namespace Foo\Bundle\Admin\SiteRoutingBundle\Routing;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Routing\Router;
use Foo\Bundle\Common\CoreBundle\Manager\SiteManagerInterface;

class AdminSiteRouter extends Router
{
    const USE_SITE_HOST  = true;
    const USE_SITE_PARAM = false;

    protected $siteManager;

    public function setSiteManager(SiteManagerInterface $siteManager)
    {
        $this->siteManager = $siteManager;
    }

    public function generate($name, $parameters = [], $referenceType = self::ABSOLUTE_URL)
    {
        // some code
    }
}
```

Neither in this class, or the extended class `Router` from the FrameworkBundle has a dependency to `LoaderInterface`.

The autowiring config for this class:

```
Foo\Bundle\Admin\SiteRoutingBundle\Routing\AdminSiteRouter:
    arguments:
        $resource: '%site_routing_file_path%'
        $options: []
    calls:
        - [setSiteManager, ['@Foo\Bundle\Common\CoreBundle\Manager\SiteManagerInterface']]
```

Comment: strict_mode is always true for 4.x so I suppose you could remove it.  Probably won't help.  Guessing you are upgrading from a 3.x app?  The Router constructor has two container injections.  Wonder if that is a problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like having two container arguments is causing the problem.  Using a fresh 4.1.1 install I got the same error.  Fixed it with:

```
# services.yaml
App\Service\AdminRouter:
    arguments:
        $container: '@service_container'
        $parameters: '@service_container'
        $resource: 'resource'
        $options: []
```

My admin router was simply:

```
namespace App\Service;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Routing\Router;
class AdminRouter extends Router
{
}
```

For reference, the framework router looks like:

```
public function __construct(
    ContainerInterface $container, 
    $resource, 
    array $options = array(), 
    RequestContext $context = null, 
    ContainerInterface $parameters = null, 
    LoggerInterface $logger = null)
{
```

Notice the two ContainerInterface arguments.  I think this is confusing autowire.  Might even be a bug.

Comment: You're a life saver ! ❤️ Thank you. (Btw, I think you meant 3.4.1 and not 2.4.1 for your version)

Comment: FYI I reported the possible bug providing your context here: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/27822

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Drupal 9 , and I face this issue too afte unstall an reinstall commerce_shipping module,
please how did ypu solve it ?

Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException: The service "commerce_currency_resolver_shipping.order_processor" has a dependency on a non-existent service "commerce_shipping.order_manager"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).