# Problem implementing FosUser with Symfony4

Tags: php, fosuserbundle, symfony4

I want to use FosUserBundle with symfony 4. To do that, i use this : https://vfac.fr/blog/how-install-fosuserbundle-with-symfony-4

But when i finished I have this error message : **The service "fos_user.util.password_updater" has a dependency on a non-existent service "security.encoder_factory".**

I can't found anything in google about this. How can I resolve this problem.
Thanks a lot

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Service xxx has a dependency on a non-existent service" which seems not true?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51150361/service-xxx-has-a-dependency-on-a-non-existent-service-which-seems-not-true)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, we gave up the use of FosUserBundle with symfony 4.
Multiple threads on internet say it's impossible without updating this package.